# forward/backward euler order 1, crank nicolson order 2

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

im doing an exercise sheet and i am very confused about how to do this question.

prove forward and backward euler methods are of order 1 and crank nicolson is of order 2.

all i have is the actual equations for each:

Forward: $U^{n+1} = U^n + \tau f(t_n,U^n)$

Backward: $U^{n+1} = U^n + \tau f(t_{n+1},U^{n+1})$

Crank Nicolson: $U^{n+1} = U^n + \tau f(t_{n+\frac{1}{2}},U^{n+\frac{1}{2}})$

many thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that you are solving an equation of the form

$$
\frac{dU}{dt} = f(t,U)
$$
where we let $t_{n+1}=t_n+\tau$ describe our time step. Note that $U=U(t)$.

Now, we choose, as a reference the point where we're evaluating $f$. That is, for forwards Euler, we choose $t_n$ as our reference time, whereas for Crank-Nicolson, we choose $t_{n+\frac12}$ as our reference time.

I'll demonstrate for the case of forwards Euler. I'll leave backwards Euler and Crank-Nicolson for you to do for yourself.

Now, with $t_n$ as our reference point, we see that $U^n$ and $f(t_n,U^n)$ are exact numbers. Meanwhile, we may write that

$$
U^{n+1}=U(t_{n+1})+\epsilon_{n+1}=U(t_n+\tau)+\epsilon_{n+1}
$$
where $\epsilon_{n+1}$ is the error introduced by our iterative method - that is, it's the difference between the exact solution, $U(t_{n+1})$, and our numerical value, $U^{n+1}$. Expanding the function as a taylor series, we get
$$
U(t_n+\tau) = U(t_n)+U'(t_n)\tau+\frac{U''(t_n)}2\tau^2 + O(\tau^3)
$$
Now, we know that $U'(t_n)=\frac{dU}{dt}(t_n)=f(t_n,U^n)$. So this is equivalent to
$$
U(t_n+\tau) = U(t_n) + \tau f(t_n,U^n) + \frac{U''(t_n)}2\tau^2+O(\tau^3)
$$
Substituting everything back into the forwards Euler method, we get

$$
U^n+\tau f(t_n,U^n) + \frac{U''(t_n)}2\tau^2+O(\tau^3)+\epsilon_{n+1} = U^n+\tau f(t_n,U^n)
$$
This gives us
$$
\epsilon_{n+1} = -\frac{U''(t_n)}2\tau^2+O(\tau^3)
$$
This is the error for a single time step using Forwards Euler, and thus, for a single time step, the error is order 2.

But of course, one doesn't generally only do a single time step. Suppose that you want to go from $t=0$ to $t=T$. For $N$ time steps, the step length is $\tau=T/N$. And so, the total error, $E$ produced by taking $N$ time steps is

$$
E=\sum_{n=1}^{N} \epsilon_n = N \bar \epsilon
$$
where $\bar\epsilon$ is the average error. And the average error will also be $O(\tau^2) = O(N^{-2})$. So $E\approx O(N^{-1})$ or $E\approx O(\tau)$. So Forwards Euler method is order 1.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and help. you've helped me out massively. once again it is much appreciated